# Calculate percentile in Excel 2010 using custom vba function

Tags: vba, excel, percentile

I don't have experience in vba, and I need to convert this percentile function to a custom vba function

```
=PERCENTILE(
IF('RAW JO TIME'!$J$2:$J$51816=$A7, 
  IF($B$4="(All)",'RAW JO TIME'!$P$2:$P$51816, 
    IF('RAW JO TIME'!$M$2:$M$51816=$B$4,'RAW JO TIME'!$P$2:$P$51816)
  )
),
E$6)
```

Where $A7, $B$4 and E$6 should be passed as parameters...

I have been trying different approaches, but none work. Searching in forums I found a possible solution would be this:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF('RAW JO TIME'!$J$2:$J$51816=" & InputRange & ", IF($B$4=""(All)"",'RAW JO TIME'!$P$2:$P$51816, IF('RAW JO TIME'!$M$2:$M$51816=$B$4,'RAW JO TIME'!$P$2:$P$51816)))"
```

Where "InputRange" is a cell passed as paramters which has the value being searched in the other sheet's range...

Also tried this

```
Dim r As Range

Set r.FormulaArray = "=IF('RAW JO TIME'!$J$2:$J$51816=$A7, IF($B$4=""(All)"",'RAW JO TIME'!$P$2:$P$51816, IF('RAW JO TIME'!$M$2:$M$51816=$B$4,'RAW JO TIME'!$P$2:$P$51816)))"
```

As you can see, I didn't use parameters for this one, just trying to test the array formula as is... but I get the same result. The execution stops in the Set r.FormulaArray

To my understanding, this IF statement will return the range of cells or data matrix that afterwards will be used by the Percentile function...

But then, when I debug the code, it gets stuck there in ActiveCell.Formula... why could it be?

I am wondering if the best solution in this case would be to implement each one of the "if's" in the function as a VB if statement?

Help will be appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: That's valid, that's an array formula.

Comment: @jprealini You need to at least know how to get started on VBA. One simple way would be to reconstruct the formula and use Application.Evaluate().

Comment: @Dave.Gugg, as I explained, I need to create a custom PERCENTILE function, using as the matrix for it a range of data that will be result of the "IF" statement and comparisons you see up there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did to solve this one...

I started to play around with the Evaluate method, running just the "IF" block, and found that it returned an array which contained a "false" for records not matching the condition, and the value needed for those that did... so I first passed all the ranges as parameters, and used them to build the IF (array formula), then passed it to the Evaluate method, and used the resulting array to build the final array of values that will be passed to the WorksheetFunction percentile method (important note: result and ranges need to be declared as arrays... else it won't work, or at least didn't work for me):

```
Dim result() As Variant
Dim ranges() As Variant
Dim i, j, k As Integer
Dim func As Variant
```

func = "=IF('" & officeRangeSheet & "'!" & officeRangeAddress & "=" & officeValue.Address & ",IF('" & statusRangeSheet & "'!" & statusRangeAddress & "=" & statusValue.Address & ",IF(" & yearFunctionString & ",'" & valuesRangeSheet & "'!" & valuesRangeAddress & ")))"

```
result = Application.ActiveSheet.Evaluate(func)

    For i = 1 To UBound(result)
        If result(i, 1) <> False Then
            ReDim Preserve ranges(1 To k + 1)
            ranges(k + 1) = result(i, 1)
            k = k + 1
        End If
    Next i

CustomPercentileWFC = Application.WorksheetFunction.Percentile(ranges, Percentile)
```

The complex thing here was that in some cases the PERCENTILE function would get really huge, so the EVALUATE method was failing due to the 255 characters limitation, that's why I had to break it down in two parts...